# How to use Rails.cache.fetch from common method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I am using rails cache in my application for caching Active Record queries. I used a common method for `Rails.cache.fetch`, but it doesn't fetch the key. Am I missing anything here?

```
author = cache_fetch("author_id:#{current_user.id}") do
  Author.find(current_user.id)
end
```

In my lib file:

```
cache_fetch(key)
  Rails.cache.fetch(key,expires_in: 30.minutes)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#fetch` takes a block, which is executed and the return value of which is cached if the key was not found in the cache. You should be using:

```
cache_fetch(key, options = {}, &block)
  Rails.cache.fetch(key, options.reverse_merge(expires_in: 30.minutes), &block)
end
```

If you don't pass the block, then Rails won't know what to cache in the event of a miss, and thus won't have anything to return. The addition of the optional `options` key allows you to pass overrides to `cache_fetch` that will then get passed onto `#fetch`, while still providing for defaults.